# Python Dictionary Key value Compare

Tags: python, dictionary

So I am teaching myself Python and am stuck in a program .

```
print('How many student recors you want to en')
number = raw_input()
number = int(number)
for increment in range(0,number) :
    student_increment= {}
    student_increment['marks'] =int(raw_input('Enter Marks') )
    student_increment['position']=0
    secondincrement = increment
    student_secondincrement = student_increment

for increment in range(0,number):
    for secondincrement in range(0,number):
        if int(student_increment['marks']) < int(student_secondincrement['marks']) :
          student_increment['position']=int(student_increment['position'])+1

for increment in range(0,number):
   print( student_increment)
```

So 1st I ask the user how many student records and then make Student_0 , student_1 etc as different dictionaries as student_increment. I take all records then compare the marks in different dictionaries to find out their positions(equivalent to rank in the class ) .

From what I've tested and tried my if statement is not executed and if I try to print student_secondincrement at #1comment's place it always prints my last student_increment entry . Can someone tell me why this happens ?

Comment: Your indentation is broken, and indentation is important in Python. **You MUST make sure your code looks EXACTLY here like on your machine** for us to help you with your problem. If we "fix" the indentation like we think it would be correct, we might simply add another problem or fix yours on the way.

Comment: That isn't how variable names work, you aren't making student_#, you are just remaking student_increment over and over again. Also, you shouldn't be using multiple dictionaries for this, use classes and objects.

Comment: @Natecat oh! ok I see it now thanks for pointing this out